# Querying cosmosdb container via powershell showing only system defined columns instead of custom columns

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I tried querying cosmosdb container using azure powershell from azure portal with powershell modules. The result I am getting is only system defined columns instead of custom defined columns too. What should I do in order to get all columns provided in the select query?
Below is the code that was executed on via azure runbook.

```
$CosmosDB_Name = "dbname"
$Abt_RG_Name = "RGName"
$accountName="Acc"

$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $accountName -Database $CosmosDB_Name -ResourceGroup $Abt_RG_Name  

$query="SELECT s.visibleSalesOrderId,c.requestTimestamp,c.acquirerAction,c.statusCode,(c.statusCode='2200')? 'Success': (c.statusCode='2109')? 'Declined': (c.statusCode='2115')? 'Timeout': (c.statusCode='2110')? 'Could not Process': (c.statusCode='2111')? 'ConcurrentProcess':(c.statusCode='2300')? 'JSON_message_isEmpty': ((c.statusCode='2102')? 'InternalServerError':'Unknown') AS StatusDescription, s.acquirerRetryCounter
from salesorder s join c IN s.acquirerLog where
s.visibleSalesOrderId in ('64738389hdh')"

$Data= Get-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId 'salesorder' -Query $query  -QueryEnableCrossPartition $true  -verbose  
$Data
```

```
Result I got is below system properties only.

id           : 
_etag        : 
_rid         : 
_ts          : 
_attachments :
```

```
Expected result is custom defined columns(present in select list of above query) are below.

        "visibleSalesOrderId": "57P702M2hdhsdGC",
        "requestTimestamp": "2021-12-15T18:03:42.000Z",
        "acquirerAction": "endCycldde",
        "statusCode": "2188",
        "StatusDescription": "Declined"
```

[image]

Comment: How is this question different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577726/connecting-cosmosdb-and-executing-a-query-on-a-container-using-powershell-urge) posted 2 hours ago? Also: Both questions, as written, are off-topic: you've shown no work. You need to include your exact powershell query, expected results, actual results, errors, etc. Also, it's very important to show any type of code and output as formatted text, not an image of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Comment: Where does `Get-CosmosDbDocument` come from? It isn't part of [Az.CosmosDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/?view=azps-7.0.0).

Comment: @Mano - there is no need to tag people here - this isn't how this site works. It's just a programming Q&A site, without any official SLA, and it's not the place to request specific people to help.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Ok Sure, will take that back. Thank you

Comment: @Richard We have imported module CosmosDB into runbook account which consists of these cmdlets. CosmosDB module was imported along with Az.CosmosDB.   I referred this https://4sysops.com/archives/interact-with-azure-cosmos-db-with-powershell/ for above coding.

Comment: This is not the supported Az.CosmosDB Powershell but comes from an open source 3rd party. I recommend you direct your question to their GitHub issues list here. https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB/issues